# 802.1x renewals under linux with a bridge device

Tags: linux, fedora, bridge, wpa-supplicant, 802.1x

I have a Fedora 33 linux machine running in an 802.1X environment.  NetworkManager is configured to have an ethernet device doing the 802.1X part and a bridge device configured to do DHCP.  (I'm using a bridge so that a VM running via KVM can do its own DHCP. And the KVM machine, a windows box, is doing its own 802.1X authentication.)  I'm configuring the bridge interface to pass the 802.1X traffic by setting the bitmask in the group_fwd_mask sys file.  And it works - when I bring up the interface it properly authenticates and I get access.   But 12 hours later the machine drops off the network because it's no longer authenticated.  If I bring the interface down and up again it's properly authenticated... but I want to know why the wpa_supplicant isn't re-authenticating me prior to that 12 hour timeout.  What am I missing?

NetworkManager configs are as follows:

```
==> ifcfg-em1
HWADDR=<my_mac>
TYPE=Ethernet
NAME=em1
UUID=<interface_guid>
DEVICE=em1
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
KEY_MGMT=IEEE8021X
IEEE_8021X_EAP_METHODS=TLS
IEEE_8021X_IDENTITY=<my_identity>
IEEE_8021X_CA_CERT=<path_to_root_ca>
IEEE_8021X_PRIVATE_KEY=<path_to_private_key>
IEEE_8021X_CLIENT_CERT=<path_to_public_key>

==> ifcfg-br0
DEVICE=br0
STP=no
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DNS1=<dns_server_1>
DNS2=<dns_server_2>
DOMAIN=<DNS_search_domains>
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
NAME=br0
UUID=<bridge_guid>
ONBOOT=yes
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
PEERDNS=no
BRIDGING_OPTS=group_fwd_mask=49144
IPV6_DISABLED=yes
```

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Your post helped me passing dot1x traffic over the bridge interface using the below line:
*BRIDGING_OPTS=group_fwd_mask=49144*

Did you find a solution for your main issue as I still facing similar issue, if I disconnect the interface from the other side no dot1x auth initiated from the Linux side.

Thanks,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).